# Finding the closest to value in two datasets using a for loop

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

In MATLAB, I am able to find to identify the values in data_b that come closest to the values in data_a, alongside the indices that indicate in which place in the matrix they occur, with the following code:

```
clear all; close all; clc;

data_a = [0; 15; 30; 45; 60; 75; 90];
data_b = randi([0, 90], [180, 101]);

[rows_a,cols_a] = size(data_a);  
[rows_b,cols_b] = size(data_b);

val1 = zeros(rows_a,cols_b);
ind1 = zeros(rows_a,cols_b);

for i = 1:cols_b
    for j = 1:rows_a
        [val1(j,i),ind1(j,i)] = min(abs(data_b(:,i) - data_a(j)));
    end
end
```

Since I would like to phase out MATLAB (I will be out of a license eventually), I decided to try the same in python, without any luck:

```
import numpy as np

data_a = np.array([[0],[15],[30],[45],[60],[75],[90]])
data_b = np.random.randint(91, size=(180, 101))

[rows_a,cols_a] = data_a.shape
[rows_b,cols_b] = data_b.shape

val1 = np.zeros((rows_a,cols_b))
ind1 = np.zeros((rows_a,cols_b))

for i in range(cols_b):
    for j in range(rows_a):
        [val1[j][i],ind1[j][i]] = np.amin(np.abs(data_b[:][i] - data_a[j]))
```

The code also produced an error that made me none the wiser:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.int32 object
```

If anyone could find time to explain why I am an ignorant fool by indicating what I did wrong, and what I could do to fix it, I would be grateful as this has proven to become a major obstacle for my progress.

Thank you.

Comment: I am wondering how is your MATLAB code even working. The dimensions of `val1` and `ind1` are different and still you are able to use i and j index in the same for loop?

Comment: You don't *have* to group everything into square brackets in MATLAB you know. Only if you have multiple elements (such as in `data_a`), but not around the individual elements...

Comment: Bazingaa, they appear to be identical 7x101 matrices (albeit my knowledge is limited, and I may have misunderstood your comment). I know, Adriaan -- I copied it from python to MATLAB due to laziness. I apologize if you found it misleading.

Comment: Is there a reason you want `data_a` to be of that shape (e.g. `(7, 1)`)?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a sample input / output with smaller sizes? (I assume `data_a` can have only two points and also `data_b` can be reduced to fewer elements for testing purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are facing two problems:

1. Incorrect use of slicing for multidimensional arrays: use `[i, j]` instead of `[i][j]`
2. Improper translation of `min()` from MATLAB to NumPy: you have to use both `argmin()` and `min()`.

Your fixed code would look like:

```
import numpy as np

# just to make it reproducible in testing, can be commented for production
np.random.seed(0)

data_a = np.array([[0],[15],[30],[45],[60],[75],[90]])
data_b = np.random.randint(91, size=(180, 101))

[rows_a,cols_a] = data_a.shape
[rows_b,cols_b] = data_b.shape

val1 = np.zeros((rows_a,cols_b), dtype=int)
ind1 = np.zeros((rows_a,cols_b), dtype=int)

for i in range(cols_b):
    for j in range(rows_a):
        ind1[j, i] = np.argmin(np.abs(data_b[:, i] - data_a[j]))
        val1[j, i] = np.min(np.abs(data_b[:, i] - data_a[j])[ind1[j, i]])
```

However, I would avoid direct looping here and I would make good use of broadcasting:

```
import numpy as np

# just to make it reproducible in testing, can be commented for production
np.random.seed(0)

data_a = np.arange(0, 90 + 1, 15).reshape((-1, 1, 1))
data_b = np.random.randint(90 + 1, size=(1, 180, 101))

tmp_arr = np.abs(data_a.reshape(-1, 1, 1) - data_b.reshape(1, 180, -1), dtype=int)
min_idxs = np.argmin(tmp_arr, axis=1)
min_vals = np.min(tmp_arr, axis=1)
del tmp_arr  # you can delete this if you no longer need it
```

where now `ind1 == min_idxs` and `val1 == min_vals`, i.e.:

```
print(np.all(min_idxs == ind1))
# True
print(np.all(min_vals == val1))
# True
```

Comment: Thank you very much, norok2! Excellent! This is exactly what I have been trying (and failing) to do! If you do not mind me asking (a bit off-topic), but is there a way to list all  `data_b` positions in which the number (`data_a`) occurs instead of just the first occurrence? Your solution is what I was after, whereas the other is just a curiosity for future reference.

Comment: @naughty_waves I am not aware of a function that find all the global maxima/minima kind of out of the box, and I guess this has to do with the fact that you may want to get results with consistent dimensions (what if there are 2 minima in one series and 3 in another, what should the shape of the result be?). Anyway, if you have an array `arr` for which you know the value of the minimum `min_arr` you could just get a mask selecting all those values by `arr == min_arr`. To get the indices you would use `np.where(arr == min_arr)`.

Comment: I understand -- I am quite new to all of this so it helps a lot when experienced users sets me straight. Thank you again, @norok2.:)

Answer (score 0):

Your error has to do with "[val1[j][i],ind1[j][i]] = (a single number)". You are trying to assign a single value to it which doesn't work in python. What about this?

```
import numpy as np

data_a = np.array([[0],[15],[30],[45],[60],[75],[90]])
data_b = np.random.randint(91, size=(180,101))

[rows_a,cols_a] = data_a.shape
[rows_b,cols_b] = data_b.shape

val1 = np.zeros((rows_a,cols_b))
ind1 = np.zeros((rows_a,cols_b))

for i in range(cols_b):
    for j in range(rows_a):
        array = np.abs(data_b[:][i] - data_a[j])
        val = np.amin(array)
        val1[j][i] = val
        ind1[j][i] = np.where(val == array)[0][0]
```

Numpy amin does not return an index so you need to return it using np.where. This example does not store the full index, only the index of the first occurrence in the row. Then you can pull it out since your row order matches your column order in ind1 and data_b. So for instance on the first iteration.

```
In [2]: np.abs(data_b[:][0] - data_a[j0])
Out[2]: 
array([ 3, 31, 19, 53, 28, 81, 10, 11, 89, 15, 50, 22, 40, 81, 43, 29, 63,
       72, 22, 37, 54, 12, 19, 78, 85, 78, 37, 81, 41, 24, 29, 56, 37, 86,
       67,  7, 38, 27, 83, 81, 66, 32, 68, 29, 71, 26, 12, 27, 45, 58, 17,
       57, 54, 55, 23, 21, 46, 58, 75, 10, 25, 85, 70, 76,  0, 11, 19, 83,
       81, 68,  8, 63, 72, 48, 18, 29,  0, 47, 85, 79, 72, 85, 28, 28,  7,
       41, 80, 56, 59, 44, 82, 33, 42, 23, 42, 89, 58, 52, 44, 65, 65])

In [3]: np.amin(array)
Out[3]: 0

In [4]: val
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: np.where(val == array)[0][0]
Out[5]: 69

In [6]: data_b[0,69]
Out[6]: 0
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. Unfortunately (it may very well be due to my incompetence and general stupidity), I am unable to make it work like I envisioned (and how it works in MATLAB). I want to end up with a 7x101 matrix containing the data_b values that are closest to the reference values (data_a).